# MySQL duplicate entry in multiple transactions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data in 2 tables (users & rights with a unique constraint on users.name) using transactions so I got a SQL file like this :

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users(name, country, phone) VALUES ('toto', 'France', '0123456789');
INSERT INTO rights(user, app, isOk) VALUES('toto', 'myApp', 1);
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users(name, country, phone) VALUES ('tata', 'USA', '1234567890');
INSERT INTO rights(user, app, isOk) VALUES('tata', 'myApp', 1);
COMMIT;

...
```

I run the file with the command :

```
mysql -u usr -h localhost -P 3306 -p < D:\mySqlFile.sql
```

If a user with the name 'toto' already exists, I got a Duplicate entry and the lines ('toto', 'France', '0123456789') and ('toto', 'myApp', 1) are not inserted, which is logic. 
But with this duplicate entry error on the first transaction, the next transaction (user 'tata') is not run. The user 'tata' is not created, while it does not exist...
I know I can use --force, but it will create the line ('toto', 'myApp', 1) while I don't want to.
Is there a way to continue running the other transactions & not stop the file ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;  -- rollback any error in the transaction
END;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users(name, country, phone) VALUES ('toto', 'France', '0123456789');
INSERT INTO rights(user, app, isOk) VALUES('toto', 'myApp', 1);
COMMIT; -- this will not be executed
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not what i am looking for. If I add the Ignore keyword, the line ('toto', 'France', '0123456789') will not be inserted but this line ('toto', 'myApp', 1) will be, what I don't want to (there is no constraint on the table rights).
What I want is if 'toto' generates a duplicate key, then I don't insert either in users, nor right, but I go to the next transaction and insert 'tata'.

Comment: Makes sense. I updated answer. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.